# create appspec.yml file for ec2 deployment

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ssh, deployment

I have created a spring boot app that I can launch on AWS EC2 instance and it works fine, however, I would now like to automate the process using CodeDeploy, so I wouldn't have to use puTTy to connect to the instance, download the new jar file and run it manually.

My issue is that I don't know what to write in the appspec.yml file in order to:

- Stop the application
- Download the new .jar file that sits inside of .zip file in my S3 bucket (equivalent to # wget -N jarlink)
- Run the application (equivalent to # java -jar jarname)

I am aware that I need some scripts for this, however, I don't where to get the right ones.

Cheers,
Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, my appspec.yml file looks as follows:

```
version: 0.0

os: linux

files:
  - source: /artifact_name.jar
    destination: /tmp

hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: stop-process.sh
      timeout: 180
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: start-process.sh
      timeout: 180
      runas: root
```

stop-process.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef | grep artifact_name.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

start-process.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar /tmp/artifact_name.jar > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &
```

also included both script artifacts in buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn clean install

artifacts:
  files:
    - target/artifact_name.jar
    - appspec.yml
    - scripts/start-process.sh
    - scripts/stop-process.sh
  discard-paths: yes
```